# Xamarin Android App is crashing on SAMSUNG SM-A5000 and LG-H815T phone

Tags: xamarin.android

Let me explain the scenario.

1. We have developed an APP in Xamarin.android. And tested it on various emulator and some mobile phones. Those emulators and mobile phones laid into API 16 to API 23. Here App was worked fine.
2. After the development, we uploaded this app on HockyApp for testing and generating crashing reports if any exists. One of our testers has aforementioned mobile phones. and App is immediately crash on the mobile phone. I have shared a screenshot with this post.
3. Then we decided to upload the App on xamarin Test Cloud Platform. And we have tested App on various mobile phones. And it was working fine. Then I have tested App on LG-H815 mobile which is located on Xamarin Test Cloud Platform. And also app works fine.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsm7r.jpg)

Can you please suggest why App is only crashing aforementioned mobile phones.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the processor settings to armeabi-v7a only, the others are for emulator and obsoleted processors. Also make sure the target framework is high enough for this phone.

1. Go to Project options (double click on Android project)
2. Go to Android build under build section
3. Go to Advanced tab and only use armeabi-v7a
4. Test it again on your  LG-H815

We had the same problem with the Samsung S6 + 7 (edge).